# How to cleanly iterate over a list of lists to get cumulative totals conditional to another list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, conditional-statements

Consider the following code:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3],[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]] # a lot longer than this in reality
list_of_dicts =[{'vol': 3,  'key': 0},{'vol': 5,  'key': 0},{'vol': 9,  'key': 0},{'vol': 16,  'key': 0},{'vol': 33,  'key': 0},{'vol': 45,  'key': 0},{'vol': 57,  'key': 0},{'vol': 85,  'key': 0} ]  #currently 9 entries in the list, but may be more

def calculate_keys():
    accumulator,  index = 0,  0
    for value in list_of_lists:
        accumulator += value[0]*value[1]
        if accumulator >= list_of_dicts[index]['vol']:
            list_of_dicts[index]['key'] = value[0]
            index += 1
            if index == len(list_of_dicts):
                break # this line is here so that if the final key in list_of_dicts is found, no need to keep iterating over list_of_lists
            if accumulator >= list_of_dicts[index]['vol']: # these lines are repeated so that the correct keys are returned, looking to do this cleaner
                list_of_dicts[index]['key'] = value[0]
                index += 1
                if index == len(list_of_dicts):
                    break
                if accumulator >= list_of_dicts[index]['vol']:
                    list_of_dicts[index]['key'] = value[0]
                    index += 1
                    if index == len(list_of_dicts):
                        break
                    if accumulator >= list_of_dicts[index]['vol']:
                        list_of_dicts[index]['key'] = value[0]
                        index += 1
                        if index == len(list_of_dicts):
                            break
                        if accumulator >= list_of_dicts[index]['vol']:
                            list_of_dicts[index]['key'] = value[0]
                            index += 1
                            if index == len(list_of_dicts):
                                break
calculate_keys()
print(list_of_dicts)
```

It takes each entry in list_of_lists, multiplies them together and adds them to accumulator. When the accumulator is matched to a 'vol' entry in list_of_dicts, it assign the first value of list_of_lists to the corresponding 'key' in list. Not sure if this explains what I'm tring to do well, but the code works, it just look really ugly and I'm tring to make it look cleaner as well as become a better coder. Strictly speaking the repeated "if accumulator ... break" section should be repeated for the number of entries in list_of_dicts. Suggestions would be most welcome.

As stated, the code works, just trying to do it neater.

Comment: Such questions are better suited to Code Review.

Comment: you want to replace all that repetition with a loop

Answer (score 0):

The nested `if` checks are all the same, and are a consequence of tracking an index where you really don't need one. You can just check in a list comprehension/generator expression if `accumulator` matches any `vol` in the `list_of_dicts`:

```py
def calculate_keys():
    accumulator = 0

    for a, b in list_of_lists:
        accumulator += (a * b)
        
        entries = [
            entry for entry in list_of_dicts 
            if entry['vol'] == accumulator
        ]

        # check if the list is empty, if it is,
        # then the loop is over
        if not entries:
            break
        
        entry = entries[0]

        # otherwise, set on the first found value
        entry['key'] = a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all the repetition by another loop:

```
def calculate_keys():
    accumulator = 0
    for value in list_of_lists:
        accumulator += value[0]*value[1]
        for entry in list_of_dicts:
            if entry['key'] != 0:
                continue
            if accumulator >= entry['vol']:
                entry['key'] = value[0]
        

calculate_keys()
print(list_of_dicts)
```

give:

[{'vol': 3, 'key': 2}, {'vol': 5, 'key': 2}, {'vol': 9, 'key': 3}, {'vol': 16, 'key': 4}, {'vol': 33, 'key': 5}, {'vol': 45, 'key': 5}, {'vol': 57, 'key': 6}, {'vol': 85, 'key': 6}]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with this

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3],[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]] # a lot longer than this in reality
list_of_dicts =[{'vol': 3,  'key': 0},{'vol': 5,  'key': 0},{'vol': 9,  'key': 0},{'vol': 16,  'key': 0},{'vol': 33,  'key': 0},{'vol': 45,  'key': 0},{'vol': 57,  'key': 0},{'vol': 85,  'key': 0} ]  #currently 9 entries in the list, but may be more

def calculate_keys():
    accumulator= 0
    list_of_volumes = [volume['vol'] for volume in list_of_dicts]
    for value in list_of_lists:
        if not list_of_volumes:
            break
        accumulator += value[0]*value[1]
        list_of_volumes_copy = list_of_volumes.copy()
        for volume in list_of_volumes_copy:
            for dict in list_of_dicts:
                if dict['vol'] == volume:
                    dict['key'] = value[0]
            list_of_volumes.pop(0)

calculate_keys()
print(list_of_dicts)
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: **dict** has a special use in Python; best not to use it for your own variable name.

Comment: Your solution code results in a key value of 1 for every 'vol' in list_of_dicts. How is this a fix to the problem you raised.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution, it was vital in finding my solution. The assumption that you made, because it was my fault for not specifying, is that the keys in list_of_dicts are not necessarily initialized to 0. You code makes that assumption and falls over if they are non 0. My code address this. I just think the word dict both appropriate and funny in this instance. Thanks.